# Use IAM credentials for S3 Maven Repository in Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've configured an S3 backed Maven repository per the instructions [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html#example_declaring_a_s3_backed_maven_and_ivy_repository_using_iam), eg:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "s3://myCompanyBucket/maven2"
        authentication {
           awsIm(AwsImAuthentication) // load from EC2 role or env var
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert my script to use the Kotlin DSL instead of groovy, but can't figure out the equivalent code, specifically for the `authentication` portion.

What is the equivalent Kotlin DSL for the Groovy snippet above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just managed to configure a HttpHeaderAuthentication through the following:

```
maven {
    credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials::class.java) {
        name = "Private-Token"
        value = "xxxxxxx"
    }
    authentication {
        val header by registering(HttpHeaderAuthentication::class)
    }
    url = uri("https://xxxxxxxx/")
}
```

So I guess yours should be something like

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url = uri("s3://myCompanyBucket/maven2")
    authentication {
       val awsIm by registering(AwsImAuthentication::class) // load from EC2 role or env var
    }
  }
}
```

HTH

Comment: That worked! intellij complains that the variable "awsIm" is never used, but I'll take it :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work like this:

```
maven {
    url = uri("s3://$repoBucketName/release")
    authentication {
        register("awsIm", AwsImAuthentication::class)
    }
}
```

At least no warnings from unused variables. =)